# Receive Payload post in Angular 4+

Tags: angular, http, post, routes, payload

The question is that I'm doing a front module in Angular, this app that I'm doing will send it to call another application in which a user has previously logged in, my app will be going through POST the payload with the user's profile information in Json format, the question is ... How do I get in Angular4 + that payload that they are sending me ?. That is, what I want to do is something like what is done with Body Parser in NodeJs, only in Angular4 +. I am something new in this framework and the only thing I have clear is how to get parameters of GET requests, but I do not know how to do the same with POST requests.

Comment: return this.http.post(`url`, yourpostobject, { observe: 'response' }); like this you get from the API the response

Answer (score 0):

Service layer..

```
import { Http, 
         Headers,
         RequestMethod,
         RequestOptionsArgs,
         Response }           from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }         from 'rxjs/Observable';
import                             'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import                             'rxjs/add/operator/do';
webServiceCall.getdata(): Observable<Response> {
      return this.http.request(url,options)
    .do((resp:Response) => 
      {  
        console.log('getdata(): ', resp.json() ); 
      });
}
```

Component layer:

```
this.webServiceCall.getdata()
      .take(1)
      .map((resp:Response) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
          this.domainObjects:DomainClass[] = resp.json().domain_class_name_in_json as DomainClass[];
       }.subscribe()
```

There are a few redundant imports here... But this is just a taster. i.e ones you should look into. 
You will often need those. Tweak your code accordingly.

Also be sure to check out the Heroes examples in the Angular docs. Best place to start. This stuff begins about [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).